# Debugging arm-elf C code using Zylin in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, arm, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse CDT with Zylin embedded debug (native) and arm-elf-gdb 6.6 on OS X 10.5.8.
I've got an OCD debugger connecting to a board with an ARM processor.

Eclipse is able to stop at the first breakpoint and gather variables from memory, but any subsequent breakpoints or single-steps fail. I can set breakpoints ok when using commandline gdb, but setting breakpoints at the exact same location gives me these errors in Eclipse:

```
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 2.
Error accessing memory address 0x3f6: Unknown error: -1.
```

And my OCD connection dies with `"Error: unexpected error -308"`

I'm using the same OCD script in both cases.

The only differences I see are (1) Eclipse uses Zylin and the mi protocol to talk to gdb, and (2) my gdb script is invoked differently in this way:

When running from gdb, I use a script file that ends with these two lines:

```
load        filename.out
symbol-file filename.out
```

In Eclipse, I copy the contents of this script file into "Debug Configurations | Commands" (I've tried both the "'Initialize' Commands" and "'Run' Commands" boxes.  I replace the last two lines with `load`, and specify `filename.out` in the "Debug Configurations | Main | C/C++ Application" box.

I'd appreciate any suggestions about how to get Zylin+Eclipse to behave. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same solution on a LPC2103.

Go to Eclipse, in `Zylin Debug Configurations > Embedded Debug (Native)`:

**Main tab:** C/C++ Application = `you_elf_file.elf`

**Debugger tab:** GDB debugger = `arm-elf-gdb`; GDB command set = `Standard`; Protocol = `mi2`

**Commands:**

'Initialize' commands:

```
target remote localhost:3333

monitor arm7_9 dcc_downloads enable
monitor arm7_9 fast_memory_access enable
monitor arm7_9 dbgrq enable

monitor reset halt
monitor wait_halt
monitor sleep 500
load
```

'Run' commands:

```
continue
```

I'm using parallel port Wiggler and OpenOCD [Open On-Chip Debugger 0.4.0] with the cfgs that came with the installation:

```
openocd -f interface/parport.cfg -f target/lpc2103.cfg
```

It works most of the time for me.